# JCE Editor toggle editor button missing V2.9.32

Tags: joomla-3.x, jce

I manage quite a few Joomla sites and following a stint of updates I've noticed that the Toggle editor button is missing on sites with JCE 2.9.32 Joomla 3.10.11.

[image: jce toggle]

I had some sites which I was yet to update so tested the Joomla update first, which did not remove the editor button, the JCE update did. I checked the changelog for JCE and didn't see anything relating to this so I wanted to get some feedback from others before reporting a potential bug. It's a feature I use quite often.

Comment: Welcome back Dtorr!  I was worried that we lost you.

Comment: @mickmackusa I guess I have been MIA. Thanks for noticing. Not intentional just haven't had any strange requests or issues of late....thankfully. I think I have most of my customers stable...although I'm sure there will be a new influx with the J4 migrations.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue some versions back. You can **configure the toggle switch** in your JCE **Profile**.

In the Joomla back-end: Components > JCE Editor (Pro) > Profiles > select the profile that you are using > go to the [Features & Layout] tab > set `Editor Toggle` to Yes.

Comment: I am using JCE editor Pro. I just read that this "Editor Toggle" option is only available in the Pro version, see: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32528/13472

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to this, I contacted JCE and they advised the toggle is now only available in the pro version.

> Hi,
>
> The Toggle Editor button is now only available in JCE Pro.
>
> You can access the HTML code in JCE Core by clicking the Code tab
> above the editor toolbar.
>
> Thank you,
>
> ####### JCE Developer
>
> JCE - A Content Editor for Joomla!®

It's no biggie really I guess, I've just been so used to it, the code tab just seems to display a different font/font size. I'm a creature of habit.

I hope this answer is of use in case anyone else is also a creature of habit.

D

Answer (score 0):

Actually u have to go to component> JCE pro> Profiles> Default> features/layout > scroll all the way down till Editor State > turn it on :)

Comment: Welcome Morgan, Thank you for your input - my update does state that the toggle is now only available as part of JCE Pro - it was previously available in the free version. You seem to be using JCE Pro which gives the extra options.